# Minimizing an open box (Calc I)

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization

> A rectangular container with an open top is to have a volume of $12 \;\text{m}^3$. The length of its base is twice the width. Material for the base costs (in dollars) 10/$\text{m}^2$. Material for sides is 7/$\text{m}^2$. Find cost of materials for the cheapest such container (minimize cost).

$V=12\;\text{m}^3$
$L=2W$

$C=10LW+7(2)WH+7(2)LH$

$V=12=LWH$
$12=2W\times W \times H \implies \dfrac{12}{2W^2}=H, \dfrac{6}{W^2}=H$

$C(W)=10(2W)W+14(W)(\dfrac{6}{W^2})+14(2W)(\dfrac{6}{W^2})$
$C\;'=40W-\dfrac{84}{W^2}-\dfrac{168}{W^2}=0$
$W=\sqrt[3]{6.3}$

Then I input $W=\sqrt[3]{6.3}$ into the cost function and got $262.44$ as the total cost, but it is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct up to the last step. Somehow, you made a mistake inputting $\sqrt[3]\frac{63}{10}$ into the cost function:

$$C(W)=20W^2+\frac{252}{W}$$

The answer should be $\$ 204.67$.